# Autowiring a decorator in Spring

Tags: spring

I am using the decorator pattern to decorate a service class with a caching service class.

Without Spring, I would inject it as follows:

```
private IService is = new CachingService( new RoleService());
```

Note that, consistent with the Decorator pattern, both `CachingService` and `RoleService` implement the `IService` interface.    `CachingService`, as a decorator of an `IService` has a constructor that takes an `IService` argument.

Is there a way to autowire this using Spring annotations?

In case it would help, I imagine something LIKE this:

```
 @Autowire(with=CachingService, constructor-arg-ref=RoleService)
 private IService is;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define CacheService as separate sprint bean:

```
<bean id="cacheService" class="CachingService">
    <constructor-arg type="innerService">
         <bean id="roleService" class="RoleService">
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

After this you can autowire spring bean by name:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("cacheService")
private IService service;
```